# How to render a HTML form-data that has redirect action get from API in Next.js

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Assume that I have an address `/api/pay` that when I call it will return the below data:

```
<html>
      <body>
        <form id="paymentForm" action="http://localhost:4000/MyVirtualGateway" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="CommandType" value="request"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="trackingNumber" value="5503474321343265518"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1679600"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="redirectUrl"
                   value="http://localhost:4000/api/payments/bankPayments/verify?paymentToken=b3f093ae4cda4c5fb0fb14aa8b7b1ff4"/>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('paymentForm').submit();</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I need to render it in order to redirect clients automatically http://localhost:4000/MyVirtualGateway. Is there any way to do that? How should I render the result to fire the submission form and get redirected to the target page?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.onLoad`  to run thing as soon  as the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onLoad (() => document.getElementById('paymentForm').submit();)  
</script>
```

Comment: the problem is I want to render the API result inside a page component that already rendered

Answer (score 0):

you can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}} />
```

- data: is string

Example with your code

```js
const Form = `<html>
  <body>
    <form id='paymentForm' action='http://localhost:4000/MyVirtualGateway' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='CommandType' value='request'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='trackingNumber' value='5503474321343265518'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='1679600'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='redirectUrl'
               value='http://localhost:4000/api/payments/bankPayments/verify?paymentToken=b3f093ae4cda4c5fb0fb14aa8b7b1ff4'/>
    </form>
    <script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('paymentForm').submit();</script>
</body>
</html>`;
const Pay = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Payment</h1>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: Form }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pay;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```